# Would it be acceptable like if you don't want to wear a t-shirt for a team video shoot in a large organization for some reasons?

Tags: ethics, employer-relations, relationships, dress-code, uniforms

The full details, if you want to read, are written under [this](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/21901/how-do-i-effectively-explain-to-my-boss-that-i-cant-wear-a-t-shirt-for-our-offi?noredirect=1#comment87440_21901) question

In short, due to privacy reasons, possible reactions by people who know me, my lifestyle, my background, my shape and my inability to not handling the outcome of a situation when something goes against my self-respect... I don't want to wear a t-shirt in our team video shoot.

If I wore a t-shirt, I would feel so uncomfortable (due the change, not because it's not comfortable) during video and in coming months. It would be little hard to remove the thoughts.

We are a team of 10-12 employees (small startup).

However, I'm ready if the thing (logo and some good graphic) is printed on a shirt, to wear it.

Now, I'm about to tell this to my boss.

Before that, I would like to know what would happen if this happened in a company like Google, Microsoft etc.?

Would they accept me the way I dress (formals) always and not wanting to wear a t-shirt even for a single day? Or will they sack me?

Comment: Duplicate here : https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/21910

Comment: I suspect the OP is hoping to get a different answer here than on the other SE site.

Comment: @JustSaying there are only two possible answers wear it or not (pretending to be sick is equivalent to not wearing it...).

Comment: @VKS please don't take this the wrong way; I just want to kindly suggest you talk to someone, maybe a professional, some kind of therapist. I think it's totally fine that you do not want to wear a t-shirt (personally, there are LOTS of clothing I would not feel comfortably wearing) but this seems to affect you a worrysome lot - you mention it would be constantly on your thoughts, etc. Maybe some work to be more self-accepting and comfortable with whatever people say would benefit you :)

Comment: If you have to worry about your friends' reactions to something as minor as wearing a company t-shirt for a team video, maybe you need different friends.

Comment: I have seen people put the t-shirt on over their normal shirts in situations that require them to wear a t-shirt for some event

Answer (score 3):

In big organizations- this wont matter. Its your personal choice, as long as you are within dress code or decent in absence of dress code, no one cares. Your boss may mention it to you casually, but thats about it. Since you have mentioned formal's, there is no way someone is firing you for that.

In start up's, rules may not be that simple. It depends on how professional owner's are. They may not fire you for this, but if someone feels you are not being a team player, they can always find a way to get what they want.

My suggestion, talk to your boss that you are not comfortable about it. Would you be willing to be left out of team video? If so, it may make it easier. Your manager may not open up to the idea of only you wearing formals for the video shoot out, but if you opt out, you will not be odd one out and draw unnecessary attention to yourself.

Comment: 1 thing. I'm the only designer there (I'm a Graphic Designer).